# How to implent GetFileType using c# to show in a document

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a newbie at c#. I'm trying to figure out how I can get this code to output in my csv file.

```
public string GetFileType(string fileSignature)
    {
        if (fileSignature == "ffd8ffe0")
            return "This is a JPG file";
        else if (fileSignature == "25504446")
            return "This is a PDF file";
        else
            return "Other file";
    }
```

I'm not sure how to write it in so it'll show in the file. I've tried every way I can think of but all I get are errors. Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Thanks so much. Updated coded added. My error is in the Main(string[] args) area. The error says "The name fileSignature does not exist in the current context. I'm not sure how I'm how it doesn't exist.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your directory location:");
        string userDir = UserDirectory();

        Console.WriteLine("\nNext your file will be compiled into a CSV.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease. Enter your CSV location:");
        string userCSV = UserCSV();

        Console.WriteLine("Your CSV file is ready now...");
        CSVList.CSVOutput(userDir, userCSV, fileSignature);
        

    }

    public static string UserDirectory()
    {
        string userDir = Console.ReadLine();
        while (Directory.Exists(userDir) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your directory does not exist. Try another location.");
            userDir = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nThis directory location will do. \nLet's move on.");
        return userDir;
    }

    public static string UserCSV()
    {
        string userCSV = Console.ReadLine();
        while (Directory.Exists(userCSV) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your CSV location does not exist. Try another location.");
            userCSV = Console.ReadLine();  
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis CSV location will do.");
        return userCSV;
    }

    public static string GetFileType(string fileSignature)
    { 
        if (fileSignature == "ffd8ffe0")
            return "This is a JPG file";
        else if (fileSignature == "25504446")
            return "This is a PDF file";
        else
            return "Other file";
    }
}

public class CSVList
{

    public static void CSVOutput(string userDir, string userCSV, string fileSignature)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(userDir, fileSignature);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(userCSV, fileSignature, @"C:\Users\nikolette\My Files\Regular Business\files.csv")))
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", file, extension, fileSignature);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "all I get are errors" it would help if you *show them*

Comment: First of all, it looks like you mistakenly used `File.Exists` instead of `Directory.Exists` in  your `UserCSV` method. This should get rid of the StreamWriter exception. What else are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I will remember to catch them and insert them next time.

Comment: @div Thanks. Ultimately I'm wanting to determines using a file signature if a given file is a PDF or a JPG. If it's not, than the csv file should say it's an "other" file instead of what type of file is it i.e doc, xcf

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a file to a location that does not exist at line 62. You concatenate the directory, file name, and "\files.csv", then try to write to that location (in my case, c:\dev\test.csv\files.csv"). The problem is that c:\dev\test.csv is a file, not a directory. You're referencing it as if it were a directory when you append the output filename to the path.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my original statement to show the full path but I put hidden to hide my full names. At 62 should I omit the full path location and just ask for the userCSV?

Comment: At line 62, you should have a path (full or relative) to the file you want to write. If you take @div's comment above and change the File.Exists to Directory.Exists so that userCSV contains a directory and not a file, then when you Path.Combine, userCSV should contain a valid value to able to write the file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm understanding. How do I call the GetFileType so it'll show in the csv file when I open it? When I add it to the CSVOutput as a string - Directory.GetFiles(userDir, fileSignature) - Path.Combine(userCSV, fileSignature, @"C:\Us - and "{0},{1},{2}", file, extension, fileSignature. CSVList.CSVOutput(userDir, userCSV, fileSignature); has an error that says "The file name does not exist in the current context. Am I not adding the fileSiganture in the right place?

Comment: Post your updated code above and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks. Updated coded posted above.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. "error CS0103: The name 'fileSignature' does not exist in the current context" line 14. I don't see any code that calls GetFileType() to get, what I assume, is the fileSignature.

Comment: May I know what type of method I could write that will call GetFileType()? I'm not sure how I can call it any other way.